# При переходе назад в браузере не учитывать якоря

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, webbrowser

Галерея фоток на сайте сделана на css используя якоря #img1 #img2 и т.д.
Проблема в том что, после просмотра фоток, если нажать назад, то естественно всплывает последнее просмотренное фото (site.ru/page2/#img1), а хотелось бы что бы был переход на предыдущую страницу. Возможно ли такое сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, но без нажатия на назад (т.к. DOM не отслеживает события связанные с нажатием на эту кнопку), придётся создать свою собственную кнопку возврата. А дальше:

```
 var clicker = 0;//Спец переменная. Отслеживает сколько раз кликнули.
  var links = document.getElementsByClassName("toLink");//Получаем наши якоря
  for(var i=0; i<links.length;i++){
      links[i].onclick = function(){
          clicker--;//Считаем сколько раз кликнули
      };
  }
  var back = document.getElementById("back");
  back.onclick(function(){
      history.go(clicker);//Возвращаемся к началу
  });
```